# Adding certification / docMDP signature using openPDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, openpdf, pdf-specification

I just stumbled over the following code in openPDF while creating a docMDP:

```
private void addDocMDP(PdfDictionary crypto) {
    PdfDictionary reference = new PdfDictionary();
    PdfDictionary transformParams = new PdfDictionary();
    transformParams.put(PdfName.P, new PdfNumber(certificationLevel));
    transformParams.put(PdfName.V, new PdfName("1.2"));
    transformParams.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.TRANSFORMPARAMS);
    reference.put(PdfName.TRANSFORMMETHOD, PdfName.DOCMDP);
    reference.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.SIGREF);
    reference.put(PdfName.TRANSFORMPARAMS, transformParams);
    reference.put(new PdfName("DigestValue"), new PdfString("aa"));
    PdfArray loc = new PdfArray();
    loc.add(new PdfNumber(0));
    loc.add(new PdfNumber(0));
    reference.put(new PdfName("DigestLocation"), loc);
    reference.put(new PdfName("DigestMethod"), new PdfName("MD5"));
    reference.put(PdfName.DATA, writer.reader.getTrailer().get(PdfName.ROOT));
    PdfArray types = new PdfArray();
    types.add(reference);
    crypto.put(PdfName.REFERENCE, types);
  }
```

This will also be put into the PDF:

```
/Reference[<</DigestLocation[0 0] /TransformMethod/DocMDP /Type/SigRef /DigestMethod/MD5  
/DigestValue(aa) /TransformParams<</P 1/V/1.2/Type/TransformParams>>/Data 5 0 R>>]
```

I changed the DigestMethod to something newer and it did just work. Also the 'aa' looks quite static and to be honest like a dummy implementation.
Any insights about what those values are? And why can they be changed without consequence?
I compared it with its predecessor *text 5 but it is the same there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your question essentially is not about OpenPDF in particular but about certain values in the **DocMDP** transform dictionary. Thus, my answer will not be focused on OpenPDF.*

In PDF versions 1.5 and 1.6 so-called *Object Digests* were used in addition to the *Byte Range Digests* in signatures with transform methods. These digests were calculated recursively over a certain set of PDF objects depending on type and parameters of the transform in question.

The **DigestMethod** value is the hash algorithm to use in object digests.

In Adobe's PDF Reference 1.7 object digests were deprecated which was made really clear in the errata:

[image: Screenshot from Errata]

In ISO 32000-1 object digests were completely removed from the text (in some cases leaving text behind which is difficult to understand).

Thus, the values you are wondering about are deprecated and are not to be used for verification purposes anymore.

You also find the reason why iText uses dummy values in the same errata:

[image: screenshot]

Thus, Adobe Acrobat 7 and 8 required some values to be there. Nowadays there is no need for them anymore.

---

In this context you may be interested in the [PDF issue 117](https://github.com/pdf-association/pdf-issues/issues/117) - the **DigestMethod** had erroneously become *required* in ISO 32000-2:2020 and this issue is about deprecating it.

Comment: OpenPDF was the starting or triggering point of my question and I had this implementation at hand thus the mentioning of openPDF. But I also saw the independence and that's why I added the #PDF-Specification Tag, too. Other than that precise as always ;-) (I always forget about those errata docs) thanks

Comment: ah, and your own answer now closes the loop back to OpenPDF... ;)

Answer (score 0):

So in openPDF we could adapt the method like this:

```
private void addDocMDP(PdfDictionary crypto) {
    PdfDictionary reference = new PdfDictionary();
    PdfDictionary transformParams = new PdfDictionary();
    transformParams.put(PdfName.P, new PdfNumber(certificationLevel));
    transformParams.put(PdfName.V, new PdfName("1.2"));
    transformParams.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.TRANSFORMPARAMS);
    reference.put(PdfName.TRANSFORMMETHOD, PdfName.DOCMDP);
    reference.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.SIGREF);
    reference.put(PdfName.TRANSFORMPARAMS, transformParams);
    reference.put(PdfName.DATA, writer.reader.getTrailer().get(PdfName.ROOT));
    PdfArray types = new PdfArray();
    types.add(reference);
    crypto.put(PdfName.REFERENCE, types);
}
```

I tried and tested it and there are no complaints from *dobe reader...